Cycle – two variants in SMILES
I have a peptide I want to cyclize head to tail. As an example I chose GGGN.
This is my cyclic peptide:
cyclized_peptide = Chem.MolFromSmiles('NC(=O)C[C@@H]1NC(=O)CNC(=O)CNC(=O)CNC1=O')

which I verified with:
Draw.MolToImage(cyclized_peptide)

to be the one I meant.
So 1N and C1 here mean nitrogen (N-terminus) and carbon (C-terminus) are bonded, right?
But cyclohexane SMILES is C1CCCCC1. If it was by the same logic as above, it should be be a cycle with five carbons, not six.
So how do the cycles work in SMILES, I am confused.
(I would also understand, if it was this way (1C instead of C1):
'NC(=O)C[C@@H]1NC(=O)CNC(=O)CNC(=O)CN1C=O', if would make sense to me if read right-to-left)

EDIT:
I am adding the images of the molecule from rdkit.
This the SMILES that gets me the molecule, but has 1N

And this is the molecule given the N1 smiles:


The SMILES specification has the ring closure and the closure identifier (e.g. 1) is given after the atom involved in the ring closure. Every closure links two atoms, so C1CCCCC1 has six atoms, and your first SMILES has 20 (non-hydrogen) atoms. The first SMILES link sC1 (at the end) with [C@@H]1 (at the start), rather than 1N. You can use this tool to test your SMILES: https://cdkdepict.cloud.vhp4safety.nl/

@EgonWillighagen I thought that too, but it does not seem the case. I created the molecule in rdkit with adding a bond between N and C. And it is what it returned and when visualized, it is correct. On the other hand, if I do N1 the visualization is not a head-to-tail cyclic peptide. I added the images in the question

The label to indicate a ring closure follows each of the atoms about the breaking point as an integer number.  Similar to an opening parenthesis and a corresponding closing parenthesis, these labels occur in pairs.  So cyclohexane can be described by C1CCCCC1:

(image credit Daylight' SMILES theory)
though C2CCCCC2 equally would be fine here because there is no ambiguity to close the loop.
However, the assignment of SMILES can be affected by the sequence of the atoms described.  Cyclic structures are a prominent, but not the only example of this, for instance 3-bromo-1-methylcyclohex-1-ene in this disconnection either described by CC1=CC(Br)CCC1, or CC1=CC(CCC1)Br:

(loc. cit.)
Second, an atom can be part of more than one cycle (think e.g., about napthalene, DABCO, etc).  The atom in question then carries multiple labels.  Daylight illustrates this on cubane eventually described here by C12C3C4C1C5C4C3C25

(loc. cit.)
This is complemented with the permitted re-use of labels after their corresponding cycles are closed which "makes it possible to specify structures with 10 or more rings" (loc. cit.) and more generally, to keep these numbers low. Daylight illustrates this on 1-(oxan-2-yl)piperidine described by O1CCCCC1N1CCCCC1:

(loc. cit.)
while PubChem uses C1CCN(CC1)C2CCCCO2.
While syntactically correct (i.e., one can recover the structure), the program/the implemented algorithm can affect the the eventually assigned SMILES string.  Hence SMILES strings e.g., by RDKit often differ from the ones e.g., by OpenBabel (even more so as OpenBabel offers a canonical*, an universal, or an inchified SMILES, ref), or GUI programs like ChemDraw, ChemDoodle, etc.  The sequence of atoms, for instance in a mol file, submitted to assign a SMILES string equally can affect assignment of the SMILES string.  Hence if you work with SMILES strings from different sources/databases, it can be helpful to "clean the data" for consistency of representation, e.g. to submit a file input.dat with records like
C2CCNCC2
c2nnncc2

to openbabel by
obabel -ismi input.dat -ocan > clean.smi

or/and relay it to the RDKit's options to sanitize molecules.
Beside the article by Wikipedia I recommend the material compiled by Daylight (theory, tutorial, and examples) as an additional read.
* For openbabel, the canonical SMILES string of a molecule will be always the same regardless of the atomic sequence in the input mol file (ref).

Thanks! I understand it now. It was helpful to see the examples, that there are multiple ways to represent the cyclic molecules.
I assumed my peptide smiles would be concatenation of each residue's smiles: NC_alpha(<side_chain in parentheses>)C(=0), and then wanted to connect first N to last C, as in head to tail cyclizing peptide bond.
I see now, that in my SMILES example the linear traversal (order of atoms in the string) does not follow strictly just the peptide backbone, but also the one side chain, and the cycle connects C_alpha and C=0, which is also correct

Oh, and http://opensmiles.org/ is a good resource too :)
